# Does java have python's equivalent of *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python, java

When implementing a java function to accept arbitrary number of arguments, what will be the right way of doing that?

In python, i will do

```
def sumUp(*args):
      res = 0
      for arg in args:
         res = res + arg
      return res

sumUp(12,1)  # return 13
sumUp(12,8,6) # return 26
```

Is there something in java closely equivalent to this without having to pass in a list argument? And what about **kwargs?

Comment: Either varargs as [explained by @shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956903/4216641) or a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of something (although the later is a little bit more syntax-heavy).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) if they're all the same type:

```
int sumUp(int... args) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int arg : args)
        res += arg;
    return res;
}
```